# Eclipse Redeploy/Undeploy Web Project without Restarting the Server

Tags: eclipse

In my eclipse web application I made a Web Project and a Library Project. The Web Project referenced the Library Project.

When I started the Server, every time I change a code in the Library Project and build it. The server wants to restart and it does not redeploy by the Web Project only. I do not want to restart the server because it takes a lot of time waiting the startup of the server.

Another is I am developing portlets using Liferay Portal and every time I change the Library Project, the auto-deploy of Liferay comes in but the Library Project Jar is locked and resulted to crash the portlet and did not deploy it until I restart the server.

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

In Java EE perspective find "Servers" tab at the bottom, delete your EAR out of there.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JavaRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/javarebel/)

Comment: I had a quick view of JavaRebel and its interesting. Going to try this one and give you feedback after testing it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but JavaRebel isn't free. I can't afford to spend too much for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the [nightly build](http://releases.liferay.com/tools/ide/eclipse/helios/nightly) of [Liferay IDE (eclipse plugins for Liferay)](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE) it has support for delta-deployment where after the initial deployment (full deploy) it will only deploy the delta or just the individual files that you change as you save them (a single JSP or CSS file, etc).